# htaccess ForceType application/x-httpd-php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is probably going to seem a little strange but we are using

```
<Files "*">
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Which of course forces all files to give html/php headers.. The reason I am doing this way is because were using a bunch of extention'less php files. I know there is plenty more efficient ways of doing this but my boss has his bizarre reasons.

Now I bet you can already spot the problem with this , without me going any further?

Yes what about your .jpg .css etc well yes thats the exactly the problem here .. moving them all to a new directory and updating all the templates would simply take hours.

So basically how I could match all except say (.css|.js|.jpg) or maybe only match files with no extension?  what ever is more efficient I guess..

Any Ideas guys?

Comment: re: 'my boss has his bizarre reasons.' - you could tell him that if you enable Options +MultiViews in apache, then you can call all scripts without the .php at the end, even though that's the filename ;) - thus /about will auto map to /about.php and so forth

Answer (score 2):

Try the [<FilesMatch>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive.

Perhaps

```
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]*$"> #Match files without a . in them - ekerner escaped period
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```